# reading string with spaces and then integers from same line in file

Tags: c, file, scanf

so the title says everything and i created a VERY simple code just to test this, and i cant get it to work.
The file has one line and it is "asd dsa:1 2 3"
i want to store "asd dsa" in a string variable, and each number in a different int variable.
this is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("file.dat","r");
  char aa[20];
  int a, b, c;
  fscanf(fp, "%[^:]%d %d %d", aa, &a, &b, &c);
  printf("%s %d %d %d\n", aa, a, b, c);
  return 0;
  }
```

and the output is

```
asd dsa 21911 1313271752 32720
```

so it is reading only the string.

Comment: That’s because the pattern `[^:]` matches a string not containing any colon, so it stops right *before* the colon and that’s the end of the scan. If you insert a colon after that pattern, the whole line should be matched

Comment: ^^^^^ i.e. `"%[^:]:%d %d %d"`

Comment: that worked, thanks mate <3

Comment: @DiegoLopes for the future, *always* check the results of `scanf` family calls to ensure the number of arguments you requested be parsed actually *were* parsed.

Comment: @WhozCraig damn didnt know they return that, thanks for telling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest in the future to learn how to debug your code. To be honest, I did not found the solution right at the top so I copied the code, and ran in on my machine and I got the wrong output, like you. Then, I debugged my code and I noticed the string is read correctly, and the numbers remain untouched. To make sure, I created a variable to hold the return value from scanf, and indeed it was 1 since only the string was getting the input.

I then first tied to add a space between `%[^:]` and `%d`, but to no avail. Then I looked at the file again, and the string I got on `aa` variable and noticed the `:` was in the file, but not in `aa`. Where did it go? nowhere, it was still in the buffer waiting to be read. In order to "skip" it, you could just add `:` sign after `%[^:]`, so the command would "eat it", and after doing it on my machine it worked.

The short answer, is to change the scanf line to:

```
fscanf(fp, "%[^:]:%d %d %d", aa, &a, &b, &c);
```

The long answer, is to learn how to debug you code correctly, It took my less than 2 minutes to figure it out and I'm sure that if you tried yourself, you could find the solution too.

Of course if you try debugging yourself with no avail, you are always welcome to open a topic!

Comment: He is evidently welcome to open a topic _even if it was not debugged_ first.

Comment: i tried for a long time to figure out how to get it to work, i knew that it was reading only the string and stopping there cuz the output of the integers where their addresses. i just didn't know how to get it to read the rest and, at the same time, stop reading to the string variable at the colon. Didnt know about that eating stuff lol

Comment: I did not mentioned noting about being welcome or not welcome to open a topic without debugging. All I suggested is to learn how to debug and trying to figure out problem yourself. I tried to explain the full thought process I had when “solving” this problem and encouraged him to try it out.